# How to check if an item is already in a listbox in vb6

Tags: random, vb6, listbox

I'm working with vb6 and I want to generate multiple randum numbers (the range from to is detirmend by user and also the number of generated answers) and send them to a listbox
But I don't want to duplicate generated numbers So..
I want before sending the generated number to the listbox to check if it already exists in the lisbox. if it already exists then generate another number if it does't then send it the the listbox

here is what I have till now
max and min are the range to chose numbers between
answers is the number of generated numbers

```
    Randomize
For i = 1 To answers Step 1
    generated = CInt(Int((max - min + 1) * Rnd() + min))
        For n = 0 To List1.ListCount
            If List1.List(n) <> gen Then
            List1.AddItem (gen)
            Else
            If List1.List = gen Then
            'I don't know what to do from here 
            '(how to go back to generate another number)
        Next n
Next i
```

Thank you in advance 
keep in minde I need to keep things simple
Thank you soo much

Comment: Be aware that by discarding some results of the generator, you are compromising the randomness of your dataset. May not matter for your purposes.

Comment: @CMaster Oh it's ok for me. I just don't want duplicates, besides no one else is affecting the result before it shows up.. so there is nothing bad with loosing some randomness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean value to keep the result if same value generated is in list.

```
Private Sub AddRandomNumbers()
    Dim blnIfFound As Boolean
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim min As Integer
    Dim answers As Integer
    max = 10
    min = 1
    answers = 5

    Randomize

    Do While List1.ListCount < answers

        generated = CInt(Int((max - min + 1) * Rnd() + min))
        blnIfFound  = False

        For n = 0 To List1.ListCount
            If List1.List(n) = generated Then
                blnIfFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n

        If blnIfFound = False Then List1.AddItem (generated)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @kitap mitap Thank you so much for answering :). I've tried your idea . there is one problem. for some reason it doesn't give all the answers for example if the answers asked by user is 5 it only givs 3 or 4 .. I don't know why

Comment: @Vbnoob You're right. Because some of the random numbers are being eliminated and no number is being generated instead of the eliminated ones.I edited the code. I replaced external `for` loop with `do` loop.